# AWS AppSync: query finds getObject by id but no listObjects filtered by id

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am using AWS AppSync for my React Native Expo project.

I am running a function where I have Tags and Posts. Before creating a tag, I check to see if the tag already exists using:

```
await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(
listTags, {filter: {tagName: {eq: "thetagnameiamcheckingfor"}}}))
```

The behavior I am seeing, is that some tags that exist are not returning from this query, even in the console. The tag does not even appear in the list when there are no filters applied at all. However, when I run `getTag` using the same id, I am returned with the correct tag. This behavior seems to be random - most tags return on `listTags`, but a select few do not. All tags are found using `getTag, {id: tagID}`

I am transforming all strings to lowercase and removing spaces so I know that is not the issue.

The tag clearly exists, why does it not return when running the `listTags` query?[image]

Comment: It could be a resolver issue. Are you using AWS Amplify or did you write your resolvers yourself?

Comment: I am using AWS Amplify so all of the resolvers are written for me. What might the issue with the resolver be?

Comment: "Whenever a client queries for a particular field, the resolver for that field fetches the requested data from the appropriate data source."
Source: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers/.
Since you're using Amplify this most likely isn't the issue. If you had written your own resolvers maybe you could have forgotten something, but in this case I'm not sure what your issue is. Given the information I have, all I can say right now is maybe try deleting your api and recreating it with the same schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB reads up to 1MB of data at a time. DynamoDB applies filters after reading up to 1MB of data. DynamoDB applies filters after applying any limits.

If you attempt to list and filter, and the items you want to find are not in the first 1MB of data read, no data will be returned. If you attempt to list and filter with a limit, and the items you want to find are not in the first $Limit items, no  data will be returned.

If you want to find items by a particular value, and that value is not a table key, you should create an index and query on that index.

Comment: this was the issue. I was able to fix it by looping nextToken through my query